# java bean not working in the same way in two different classes

Tags: java, javabeans

Here i'm attaching the java code of two classes

createnode.java class code snippet

```
NodeBean bean=new NodeBean();
double port1 = Math.random();
long portNo = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
System.out.println("portNo"+portNo);
int LineNumber = 0;
ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket((int) portNo);

bean.setNodePortNo((int)portNo);
System.out.println("portNo in create node:" +bean.getNodePortNo());
bean.setNodeName(s);

Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",(int) portNo);
```

destinationNode.java code snippet

```
NodeBean bean=new NodeBean();
int portno =bean.getNodePortNo();
System.out.println("portno"+portno);
try {
    ServerSocket   ss=new  ServerSocket(portno);
    Socket socket=ss.accept();
```

The DestinationNode.java code snippet sysout printing port no as '0' i don't what i'm missing but bean getter method not working in 2nd code snippet but it's working in first code snippet

Comment: Show full sources (if they are not big).

Comment: Not clear how are you using 'bean' variable from the first source code.

Comment: see now i have added bean object creation@Dmitry Tsechoev

Comment: You need to pass a 'bean' object from first code to second. 'bean' in first code and 'bean' in second are different objects.

Comment: You can pass 'bean' to destinationNode's constructor for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the NodeBean class create int varibale nodePortNo like this

```
private static int nodePortNo;
```

and then create setter getter methods then use those methods in your appliaction and don't declare variable for portno again in second code snippet

Answer (score 2):

In `Destination.java`

```
NodeBean bean=new NodeBean();
```

you are creating `new instance` which will be initialized with default value for fields, as its `nodePortNo` of type `int`, it will be initialized to 0.

Comment: So how can i solve this (i.e without creating new NodeBean() )?

Comment: One Approach will be to generate portNumber in static intalizer, and Source and Destination can refer to the same. Please note in case you are running separately..then you have to think either reading/writing from one common file....